# Where does SUMO locate after installing FLOW? Can we add our own models to SUMO in FLOW?

Tags: flow-project

Sorry the question may sound wierd. I'm looking for the SUMO folder but I can't locate it. Basically I want to add my new car-following model into SUMO, such that I can use the new car following model in FLOW experiments. 
I'm using Ubuntu 18, after installing FLOW, I tried to search for SUMO folder, it does not prompt out. Can anyone provide some insights? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your terminal and type:

```
which sumo
```

It should show you where you installed SUMO. Note that, SUMO and Flow are not part of the same package, so that is why you are not able to find the SUMO installed folder in your Flow folder.

In my case (macOS), I get

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ myusername$ which sumo
/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/sumo/bin/sumo
```

which means SUMO is in `/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/sumo/`

Regarding car following model, refer to https://github.com/flow-project/flow/issues/734

Comment: @ Thanks Ashkan, I think you understand my question. But here is the result I got:

I tried echo$SUMO_HOME and which SUMO, but they only tell me the location of SUMO binary.

When I installed SUMO with FLOW, I was doing scripts/setup_sumo_ubuntu1804.sh , it seems I only installed sumo_binary?

Comment: (base) hao@Hao:~$ echo$SUMO_HOME bash: echo/home/hao/sumo_binaries/bin: No such file or directory (base) hao@Hao:~$ which sumo /home/hao/sumo_binaries/bin/sumo

Comment: For you macOS, you can find sumo folder under: /Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/sumo/. But for my Ubuntu, I didn't find similar directory to my sumo. That is what puzzles me.

Comment: @PaoRaw yes it seems that you only have the binary, since Flow installs the binary. You should then install SUMO manually and ask Flow to use that installed version.